# How to recover a village linked on the same Gmail address?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When I started playing I got through TH3 and linked it to my Gmail account, but then I realized I was spending a lot of gems with that village and wanting to create another account. What I did was I uninstalled the client and re-installed it again and create another village and got through TH6 and tried to link it on the same Gmail account but it's asking me if I want to load my previous account which has TH3 which I did and now I can't go back to my TH6 village.

If anybody could help me with this one, that would greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no chance to recover your TH6 village.

Comment: seriously? :( like, there's no other way?

Comment: The village is lost unless you linked the TH6 village in some way shape or form

Comment: If you had linked to any other Gmail profiles it will be there, otherwise its lost. You can contact supercell and try your luck.